# Surpress raise errors during unittesting?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm writing unit tests for an api library, however an error (which should be showing, since that test is for failed login) is interrupting the test. Is there a way to silent raised error messages just for unit testing?

Comment: You mean like using `try:` `except:`? Or did you want to *test* that the exception is being raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [assertRaises](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) method to test that the correct Exception is getting raised. For example,

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, login, username, password)
```

where `login` is the function raising the `ValueError`, and the arguments to be passed to `login` are `username` and `password`. Note that there are no parentheses after `login` since we are *passing* the function object as an argument, not *calling* the function.